# Reasoning exercise - coloured hexagons and lines

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

All rules apply either to all rows or columns. It's obvious to me that the blue lines in the background add up from left to right. With this rule you can reduce the amount of possible solutions down to 1, 6 and 8.
Which rules determine the amount, position and color of the hexagons? What's the answer?

[image: Progressive matrix of coloured hexagons and lines]

Source: *Neuronation* app.

Comment: Well, that settles it: we all have poor cognitive abilities.  Lol

Comment:  As far as I understand, this puzzle is ment to test the cognitive ability of people that are better at logic reasoning than 99% of population. It needs to be very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea:

> [image: My idea]

Assuming

> Which rules determine the amount, position and color of the hexagons?

Implicitly implies that there could be redundant information

Comment: I think this is a valid solution. Seems like it‘s only possible to find the solution by eliminating answers.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the proposed solution. I agree that 1, 6 or 8 are the only possible options. The number of hexagons doesn't form a pattern (2,2,3 and 1,1,3) so ignore this. The colours of the hexagons in the third panel are determined by the preceding panels (red & blue, red, red & blue and blue, blue, blue) The third row's colours are black, red & blue so the third panel should have all three colours - hence the solution should be option eight. It's not a hugely satisfying solution but I think my logic is slightly more robust. I came here with a similar problem and the same logic applies - this one follows the same rules, it's vertically oriented instead of horizontally.[image: solution would be option 3]